# Footer overlapping column div

Tags: html, css

I have a nice footer but when I paste that in it overlaps the div above it (it's a mobile website.)

This is what it looks like on my phone:
[image: Right now]

This is what I want it to look like:
[image: Expected end result]

And this is the code of the area boxes at the moment:

```
<div class="area-blocks">
                <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
                    <div class="area-box">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <div class="area-file-name">
                              <span>
                                Bike trips on lombok
                              </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="area-file-type">
                                <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
                    <div class="area-box">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="area-file-type">
                                <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <div class="area-file-name">
                              <span>
                                Bike trips on lombok
                              </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
                    <div class="area-box">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <div class="area-file-name">
                              <span>
                                Bike trips on lombok
                              </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="area-file-type">
                                <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
                    <div class="area-box">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="area-file-type">
                                <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <div class="area-file-name">
                              <span>
                                Bike trips on lombok
                              </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
                    <div class="area-box">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <div class="area-file-name">
                              <span>
                                Bike trips on lombok
                              </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="area-file-type">
                                <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
                    <div class="area-box">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="area-file-type">
                                <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <div class="area-file-name">
                              <span>
                                Bike trips on lombok
                              </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the CSS for that:

```
.box-area {
    background-color: #BA5e8e;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

/* this is the boxes to align to the right */
.box-area:nth-child(2n) {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

And the footer code:

```
<div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-top">
                <h1>Villa Campi Sorga</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-left">
                <h2>Say Hello<br>to Rik Studios</h2>

                <form role="form" method="post" action="/index.php" id="footercontact" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="form-control input-sm required" role="input" aria-required="true" data-placement="top" placeholder="YOUR NAME">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control input-sm required email" role="input" aria-required="true" data-placement="top" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea type="text" rows="8" name="message" id="message" class="form-control input-sm required" role="textbox" aria-required="true" data-placement="top" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE..."></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <input type="submit" value="SEND TO US" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="button" title="Click to send!">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-right">
                <h2>How to<br>find us</h2>
                <p>Want to talk? Nice, we are ready to chat about your ideas, while sipping a cup of coffee (or tea if you like). </p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Snelliusweg 40-15</li>
                    <li>6827 DH Arnhem</li>
                    <li>The Netherlands</li>
                    <li><a href="tel:+31267074344">+31(0)26 70 74 344</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mailto:hello@axastudios.com">hello@axastudios.com</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS for that:

```
/* TEXT STYLE *************************/
#footer h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h2 {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

/* FOOTER *****************************/
fieldset {
    border: 0px !important;
}
#footer {
    position:relative;
    background: url(http://www.axastudios.com/images/bg-footer.jpg) bottom center #000000;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #777777;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
.footer-top {
    position: relative;
    padding: 60px 0px 60px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.footer-top h1{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sunshine;
    color: #fff;
}
.footer-left, .footer-right{
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.footer-left{
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#footer h2{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#footer h2:after{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#footercontact{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#footer .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#footer input.button:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    -webkit-animation: btn-animate 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: btn-animate 0.2s ease-in-out;
    animation: btn-animate 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#footer input.button {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0px;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input.button, .btn-primary {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}

#footer .form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #777;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin:0 !important;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#footer .form-control:focus {
    border-color: rgba(186, 94, 142, 255) !important;
    outline: 0px none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#footer textarea.form-control {
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%!important;
}
#footer ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#footer :-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#footer ::-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#footer :-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#footer .button{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
.footer-right{
    padding-left: 120px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    float: right
}
.footer-right ul{
    list-style: none;
    background: url(http://www.axastudios.com/images/icon-pointer.png) left 5px no-repeat;
    background-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#footer-copyright{
    background: #1c1c1c;
    border-top: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
}
.copyright{
    padding: 40px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #777777;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.footer-right a{
    color: #777777;
}
.footer-right a:hover{
    color: #ed1c24;
}

.details > p:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.copyright {
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .footer-top {
        position: relative;
        padding: 60px 40px 60px 40px;
    }
    .footer-left, .footer-right {
        position: relative;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px 25px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    a.button{
        display: block;
    }
    .mob-break{
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Sorry if I included too much code but I dont know where the problem is.

Thanks in advance!
~ Rik

Comment: This can't be the whole code. Maybe you have a link to your site?

Comment: This is indeed not the whole code. Here: http://campi.nijdeken.com/mobile/

Comment: Seems you fixed the problem, it looks good now.

Comment: @AndyTschiersch it works on the browser but not on 5 inch phones

Answer (score 0):

I don't think all your styles are included, even with loading bootstrap css it doesn't quite look like your example but if you add `.row` to the two main divs ie:

```
<div class="area-blocks row">
```

and

```
<div class="row" id="footer">
```

This should fix it.

Looking closer at your code this appears to be the issue:

```
.area {
    height: 35vh;
}
```

You will need to change this & possibly use `@media` queries to make it responsive.

If I add the following

```
.area-blocks {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 35vh;
}
```

and remove `height: 35vh` from `.area` it looks good

Comment: Doesnt fix it. Here is the full code: http://campi.nijdeken.com/mobile/

Comment: Updated my answer, you will need to use px or wrap the div in a container & re-style it.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the bootstrap collumns. Because when I delete `height: 35vh;` it should normally just adjust to the size of all the divs. But now it just stops behind the blocks? Can that be the issue

Comment: The area-block which holds the box-area divs had no height, that I believe  is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div with a class always that you include the #footer to simulate the height of the footer, for example:

Html:

```
<div class="height-footer"></div>
<div id="footer">
....
</div>
```

Css:

```
.height-footer{
    height: // here you need to put the height of your #footer
}
```

this is a trick that I use when use the footer fixed, but this trick works with all positions.

Regards!

Comment: But his footer isn't fixed: `position: relative;`

Comment: I know but that was only an example, this trick works fine with all positions